# Keep Windows 10 reserve even in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, upgrade

A month ago my laptop running Windows 8.1 had a HDD failure and I needed to install another os, so I picked Windows 10 because I had no prior experience with Linux based operating systems. Prior to this, I reserved a copy of Windows 10.

Am I still eligible for the Windows 10 reserve? Or do I need to buy Windows 10?

Comment: To take advantage of the free license off, you have to be on an eligible installation of Windows, and the Windows Insider Preview isn't eligible.  You can however, continue to use Windows 10 Insider Preview, but you must update your installation to a new build before it expires even after RTM.

Comment: Well crap, I don't have enough money to get a new version of windows.

Comment: You can install Windows 7 from a ISO and validate it with tools like loader( the internet is full of malicious copies make sure to find a clean one, reddit is a good start) i did this and still will get Windows 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Get windows 10 for free` refers to upgrading windows 7 and windows 8 installations.

This free update service is available to anyone regardless if you reserved the upgrade, and is available from 29th of July 2015 till 28th of July 2016.

In order to be able to use this, you will have to have a windows 7 or 8 installation and ugrade it to 10.

To my knowledge (but couldn't really find anything on the internet regarding this), if you want to reinstall windows 10 after the first year, you will have to buy a license.

Comment: You might want to update this question, because you won't have to purchase the license, once upgraded the machine as a perpetual license to Windows 10.